# Requesting for a post closed to be corrected as it was incorrectly closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I recent flagged a post for moderator review and it was declined for the following reason:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

My issue with this is there is no other way to point out a post was closed incorrectly as put on hold as "too broad". Without any other way to request that the closed reason for the post be changed to "duplicate" as the question was clearly a duplicate request. It was not hard to double check Stack Overflow for duplicate post and I wanted to have the closed reason changed.

If a post is closed for the wrong reason and there is some benefit we can get from a correctly closed post. Say a link to the dup Q/A that will help others who come across the post. The I think we should have some way to correct these closed post.

My question is this:

Is there a correct way to request a closed vote to be changed to something more accurate?

If not should this be a request for a new review feature?

The post in question:

[How to create child window in tkinter…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981673/how-to-create-child-window-in-tkinter)

The duplicate Q/A:

[How to keep the window focus on new Toplevel() window in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944533/how-to-keep-the-window-focus-on-new-toplevel-window-in-tkinter)

If a feature request is valid for something like this I propose we add an option for 2K+ rep users to request review of closed reason. I believe that when closing a post it should be for the correct reason as closing for duplicate would be more helpful to the readers than placing it on hold and not linking to duplicate Q/A.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40387 (but the info there contradicts with what's happening here)

Comment: and it's about 8 years old.

Comment: @user202729 The accepted answer tells the OP to do exactly what I did and I got declined lol. Yes it is contradictory.

Comment: Would be nice to get some kind of feedback on the down-votes. As I see it this question is perfectly valid and the linked question that is similar to mine has an answer that is no longer valid based on the response I got from my flag.

Comment: "There is no other way"... Of course there are other ways. You have the ability to vote to reopen the question. You can add a comment. You can @ mention the close voters in a comment. You can ask on [the SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (but do read their FAQ).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for the info. Voting to reopen would be counter to what I want to do. The question should be closed but for a different reason than what it was closed for. I have @ mentioned closed voters in the past several times just to be ignored. That said this is another reason I request the feature as it would allow others to review when the closer is ignoring the request. One last thing is I cannot use the chat as I am in a company network that blocks all forms of instant chat like the one here at stack overflow.

Comment: Here comes the "me too" down-votes. I really wish people wouldn't do this and provide a reason for down-vote.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you can only @-mention dupe hammers (and editors) on closed posts (well, you can @-mention regular close voters as well but they won't get an inbox notification, assuming that was the intent of your comment).

Comment: Ah, I thought you could... Probably mixing it up with editors. Thanks @rene.

Answer (score 5):

Duplication serves as a signpost for both the OP **and others** who have the same problem to get them to a reasonable solution.  Looking at the question which you want to close as a duplicate of another...I can concisely say that there is no reason to apply a duplicate closure reason here.

Duplicate closure addresses *otherwise* on-topic questions and attempts to get them an answer quicker.  [How to create child window in tkinter...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981673/how-to-create-child-window-in-tkinter) is not *otherwise* on-topic; there's no code or anything to go off of, and there's no clear *question* being asked - it's just a requirements dump.

So the close reason is correct.  You may have a point that the dupe *might* have helped the OP, but I don't necessarily agree; the OP didn't do enough to help us help themselves in this context.

Comment: The OPs question is 100% related to the linked duplicate answer. Anyone who has a good amount of time in tkinter can see this. Where I understand what you are saying about the question not being a good question I am 100% sure that the issue at hand is to apply the `grab()` method to the toplevel window. This is the correct solution to the OPs question.

Comment: Question moderation doesn't require domain knowledge.  If the question is too broad, I'm gonna close it as too broad, since it doesn't do anyone any good to nudge them towards a solution if I have no idea if that's the *actual* problem.

Comment: I understand that. However when a request is sent VIA a flag from a user who does have domain knowledge it should be considered and not flat out rejected. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40387/is-it-possible-to-change-a-close-reason-after-a-question-has-been-closed-and-w) tells us to flag the post and request a change. I have done this and been rejected.

Comment: I'd take that with a grain of salt; neither answerer on that post is a moderator on Stack Overflow, and the policy for questions *period* would still apply here.  If the question is bad, and closure is the only real amelioration, then keeping it closed is the best approach here.

Comment: I am not saying to reopen the post. I am simply request it to be changed to duplicate as this is more helpful to future readers and is correct in this case.

Comment: Changing the duplicate requires the post be reopened for a split second.  I also don't see how future readers are going to benefit from a requirements dump of a question.

Comment: Guess its only about closing bad questions and not about providing a good resource even if the question is badly formatted.

Comment: Yep - if the question is bad then there's no objective way to prove that providing "good" resources would even matter.  Best to let this one lie, in my opinion.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: "*I have done this and been rejected.*" ... and? That post doesn't say that the flag will be acted upon even if the moderator doesn't agree with your assessment. You flagged, the moderator said that they didn't agree, and that's the end of it. The question will eventually be deleted by the Roomba, and nothing of significance will be lost.

Comment: You say `no objective way` but there is as I have already said the question is 100% about the `grab()` method. That is fine thought. This one question is not the overall issue. There are many examples of incorrectly closed post that would benefit other readers with a correctly closed duplicate. I can see I am not going to win this one but my thought on this have not changed. Just a fact of Stack Overflow I am going to have to live with.

Comment: I'm fairly bright @Mike-SMT; I can follow context clues pretty okay with technology that I may not be familiar with.  That said, I see *no* reference to anything Python-related or Tkinter related that the OP has attempted or made a pass at which would help address their problem, nor (with my limited domain knowledge of Tkinter) could I make any mental pass at a solution.  You with your domain knowledge has immediately jumped to solutionizing the problem without really addressing the fact that there's no actual *question* being asked.

Comment: @Mike-SMT:  **It doesn't matter** if the dupe might help the OP answer the question.  **No other future asker is going to find _this_ question and be enlightened by the dupe.**  Questions here aren't just about the person that asks them.

Comment: "Questions here aren't just about the person that asks them."... That is my point. The question is not just about who asked them. My request for the duplicate is for other users to benefit. As I said this one post may not be the best example of a lager problem. There are other question that are obvious (and not a good quest) that have been closed as off topic. Again I know I am not going to win this particular case but there is an overall issue I think is not being considered.

Comment: @Mike-SMT:  The heart of the issue is if someone else is going to find the question.  If the question could be a bit more popular, then you might have a point.  I'm just not seeing how this one could be.

Comment: @Makoto this question is an example of a recent one I have run into. I brought this one up because the accepted answer on a similar post has resulted in a rejected flag and my concern was for the overall problem of post closed for the incorrect reason. I do realize this one post is not a good example of my issue but it was the most current related one I have. Thank you for you input I do understand your position on this case but my position on the overall problem is still the same.

Comment: Fair enough @Mike-SMT.  Here's hoping in the future we both find a more defensible question to discuss in this fashion.